# Can items in DynamoDB move across partitions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to see if I can write shard on the fly.

If I have a partition key of id which is a number, and then each time I write to that item, I change the id by appending `_random-value` to it, will that cause my values to move around partitions as they get updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partition key can't be updated using Update API. You will get the `ValidationException` exception.

```
Unable to update item. Error JSON: {
  "message": "This attribute is part of the key",
  "code": "ValidationException",
```

**Writes (i.e. Inserts):-**

Partition is based on **`Hash function`** result for the hash key (i.e. Partition Key).

> The output value from the hash function determines the partition in
>   which the item will be stored.